# "ensured" vs "assured"

Tags: word-usage

Which word should I use in that sentence? Ensured or assured?

"This event ________ me that this was the path I wanted to follow."

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question sentence with a slight modification:

> "This event assured me this was the path I wanted to follow."

is the correct one.

> **assure**  To give confidence to, confirm, encourage.  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/12063?rskey=VYT1Sh&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid)

and

> **ensure**  To make certain the attainment of (a result)  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/62745?rskey=tPgAzZ&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid)